# No se puede encontrar el elemento en el array primero filtrando con el método .filter( ) y luego con .includes( ) en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, filtro, javascript-metodo

En este código la idea es que funcione la combinación de los métodos .filter  y .includes tal como pasa en las líneas 18 y 21 y se pueda encontrar el elemento o no, pero el problema es que por más combinaciones que he hecho no logro ubicar el error que aparece en la consola como Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes').

Aparentemente el error se encuentra en la línea 32 donde hago item.marca.includes pero no sé si estaría accesando mal al método mediante la propiedad .marca o quizás esté accesando al array equivocado, ya que a medida que se desarrolla el código se va cambiando de array desde productos, pasando por seleccion, seleccion2, seleccion3 y así sucesivamente hasta seleccion4..

Probé eliminando el include y que funcionará solo el filter y si funcionó así, luego le agregué el include a ver y ahí viene el error… me fijé incluso que si coloco el cursor encima de los includes de las líneas 18 y 21 el VSC me da info sobre ambos métodos (igual en los .filter) pero si lo hago en el de la línea 32, aparece “any” (solo me da info en el .filter y no el .include).

Leyendo foros y hurgando en Google repasé conceptos como que el método .include trabaja con strings y no con objetos, y efectivamente le paso por parámetro un string. De hecho en las líneas anteriores me funcionó sin problemas, pero en realidad allí me trabé...

```
const productos = [
    {categoria: "botines", marca: "nike", precio: 200},
    {categoria: "botines", marca: "adidas", precio:220},
    {categoria: "botines", marca: "puma", precio: 230},
    {categoria: "botines", marca: "new balance", precio:240},
    {categoria: "camisetas", marca: "nike", precio:180},
    {categoria: "camisetas", marca: "adidas", precio:170},
    {categoria: "camisetas", marca: "puma", precio:160},
    {categoria: "camisetas", marca: "new balance", precio:150},
];

alert("Bienvenido a nuestra tienda!!")
let seleccion1 = prompt("Ingrese el tipo de producto que desea comprar: \n - botines \n - camisetas");

const seleccion = [];
if(seleccion1=="botines"){
    const seleccion2 = productos.filter((item)=>item.categoria.includes("botines"));
    seleccion.push(seleccion2);
}else if(seleccion1=="camisetas"){
    const seleccion2 = productos.filter((item)=>item.categoria.includes("camisetas"));
    seleccion.push(seleccion2);
}else{
    alert("no tenemos ese tipo de productos")
}

console.log(seleccion);

let marcas = prompt("Ingrese marca: adidas, nike, puma, new balance");
const seleccion3 = [];
if(marcas=="nike"){
    const seleccion4 = seleccion.filter((item)=>item.marca.includes("nike"));
    seleccion3.push(seleccion4); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como yo lo veo, no necesitas crear tantos Array auxiliares ni usar `push` ni nada de eso. Podrías simplemente preguntar por la categoría y la marca y hacer una sóla operación de filtrado.

En este caso y dado que indicas que quieres combinar el uso de `filter` con `includes`, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
const productos = [
    {categoria: "botines", marca: "nike", precio: 200},
    {categoria: "botines", marca: "adidas", precio:220},
    {categoria: "botines", marca: "puma", precio: 230},
    {categoria: "botines", marca: "new balance", precio:240},
    {categoria: "camisetas", marca: "nike", precio:180},
    {categoria: "camisetas", marca: "adidas", precio:170},
    {categoria: "camisetas", marca: "puma", precio:160},
    {categoria: "camisetas", marca: "new balance", precio:150},
];

const categoria = 'botines';
const marca = 'puma';

const filtrados = productos.filter(prod => prod.categoria.includes(categoria)).filter(prod => prod.marca.includes(marca));

console.log(filtrados);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

En caso de que alguno de los valores de categoria o marca no existeran en los objetos se devolvería un Array vacío:

```js
const productos = [
    {categoria: "botines", marca: "nike", precio: 200},
    {categoria: "botines", marca: "adidas", precio:220},
    {categoria: "botines", marca: "puma", precio: 230},
    {categoria: "botines", marca: "new balance", precio:240},
    {categoria: "camisetas", marca: "nike", precio:180},
    {categoria: "camisetas", marca: "adidas", precio:170},
    {categoria: "camisetas", marca: "puma", precio:160},
    {categoria: "camisetas", marca: "new balance", precio:150},
];

let categoria = 'medias';
let marca = 'puma';

const filtrados = productos.filter(prod => prod.categoria.includes(categoria)).filter(prod => prod.marca.includes(marca));

categoria = 'botines';
marca = 'under armour';

const filtrados2 = productos.filter(prod => prod.categoria.includes(categoria)).filter(prod => prod.marca.includes(marca));

console.log(filtrados);
console.log(filtrados2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

el problema que estas teniendo precisasmente es como vos pensabas, estas accediendo mal al dato.
Vos al estar haciendo (ejemplo primer if de "botines"):

`const seleccion2 = productos.filter(item ...);`
`seleccion.push(seleccion2)`

Lo que estas haciendo por detrás, es insertar un array a seleccion. Recordemos que el metodo .filter retorna un array con los resultados que matchean la condicion.

Entonces, al querer acceder a seleccion.filter, esto ya no es un **array comun** sino que es un **array que contiene arrays de objetos**.

Hacete un console.log(seleccion) en la linea de arriba del const seleccion4 para entender de que estoy hablando.

Espero te haya servido de ayuda

Comment: ¿Y esto cómo soluciona el problema? Sólo le comentas cual es su error pero no das ninguna solución. Te invito a leer [answer]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El error está al hacer push del resultado de un filter. ya que filter devuelve un array y tu en seleccion solo quieres que haya objetos me imagino. Si es así tienes que hacer:

```
seleccion.push(...seleccion2);
```

Si no, lo que meterías en el array selección sería otro array. por eso te falla al acceder a la propiedad marca en el ultimo filter, ya que el item en vez de ser un objeto es un array

Comment: ¿Y esto cómo soluciona el problema? Sólo le comentas cual es su error pero no das ninguna solución. Te invito a leer [answer]. Saludos